# Android: How do you capture a screenshot of your own app programatically

Tags: android

I know you need root access if you want to capture a screenshot by using a background application. However is it possible to just grab the screen content of your current visible activity owned by your process? This does not seem like a security constraint since the user has already installed your app is currently using your app. If so how does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can imagine to work (not tested) is to get the instance of your root layout node and manually call the [draw(canvas)](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/view/View.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) with your own canvas that was instantiated with an empty bitmap and then save this bitmap. Sounds like a lot of work but is the only thing I can think of at the moment.

Comment: yeah I thought about that but it doesn't actually give access to what is being rendered to the screen. For instance a view might be reset by the next redraw in which case if I were trying to find a defect, it wouldn't appear.

Comment: I do think this is the best option though

Comment: I have also found that grabbing the drawing cache works well too :)